# How to compare two files in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I want to compare two files (a.txt and b.txt), and write the difference into a third file c.txt.

Content of a.txt:

```
77.67.33.100 46.38.237.116 74.86.24.19 212.83.158.5 46.149.28.96 144.76.126.179 81.89.96.89 144.76.126.180 81.89.96.90 171.25.193.21 31.172.31.207
```

which is a single line with individual strings separated by space

Content of b.txt:

```
171.25.193.21 46.38.237.116 31.172.31.207 85.25.203.42 77.67.33.100 74.86.24.19 212.83.158.5 46.149.28.97
```

I need my output like this in c.txt:

```
85.25.203.42 46.149.28.97
```

means the each string in b.txt separated by space is to be compared with each string in file a.txt. Only those string not present in a.txt should be written to c.txt

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        return [s for row in inf for s in row.split()]

def write_file(fname, items):
    with open(fname, "w") as outf:
        outf.write(" ".join(items))

def main():
    a_items = set(read_file("a.txt"))
    b_items = set(read_file("b.txt"))
    c_items = b_items - a_items
    write_file("c.txt", c_items)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks hugh it works, please suggest be some book for programming in python

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
a = open('a.txt').read().split()
b = open('b.txt').read().split()
c = [x for x in b if x not in a]
open('c.txt', 'wt').write(' '.join(c)+'\n')
```

Comment: thanks jonas it works, please suggest be some book for programming in python

Comment: I can only concur with @henrebotha's suggestion: [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/). That's where I started and I found both the language itself and the tutorials excellent.