# How do I compare the content of files in Python?

Tags: python, file, compare

This is my code so far I'm trying to compare the files given by the user and printing if the content inside both files is the same. If it is the same string content I would like to print `Yes` if it's not, print `No` along with the words inside both files.

```
print ('Enter the first file name: ', end = '')
FIRST_FILE = input()

print ('Enter the second file name: ', end = '')
SECOND_FILE = input()

if SECOND_FILE == line in FIRST_FILE:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')

infile = open('one.txt', 'w')
infile.write('Hello') 
infile.close() 

infile2 = open('SameAsone.txt', 'w')
infile2.write('Hello') 
infile2.close()

infile3 = open('DifferentFromone.txt', 'w')
infile3.write('Bye') 
infile3.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you comparing the string content of the files (text-by-text), the "ID" of the files, or the byte content of the files?

Comment: The string content. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: `SECOND_FILE` and `FIRST_FILE` is a string, why you write `line in SECOND_FILE`? And what's intent for next three blocks to writing a file?

Comment: That's is just me trying things out. I'm not sure exactly how to do it

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747112/how-to-compare-two-files-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use `filecmp`

```
import filecmp
check = filecmp.cmp('file1.txt', 'file1.txt')
print ('No', 'Yes')[check]
```

If you want more information see [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html)

Comment: I love this answer! Thanks for reminding me of `filecmp` also you could do: `print ('No', 'Yes')[check]` in place of the `if: else:` just to put it out there

Comment: Edited! Thanks for the insight @Jab

Comment: Thanks this helped a bunch. Now how would I print the strings in both files under 'No'?

Comment: @skaul05 No problem, gotta love Boolean indexing

Comment: @Nanor take a look at [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) in specific `Differ.compare`. Also that may be a separate question after some research.

Comment: Seems like this does not work if the `file1.txt` file is changed during the runtime

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.read` also I suggest using the `with` statement as there would be no need to close the files manually.

```
def compare_files(fn1, fn2):
    with open(fn1, 'r') as file1, open(fn2, 'r') as file2:
        return file1.read() == file2.read()


first_file = input('Enter the first file name: ')
second_file = input('Enter the second file name: ')

print(['No', 'Yes'][compare_files(first_file, second_file)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this more efficiently using use collections module [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) method and OrderedDict preserve the order of the line.

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

with open("one.txt") as file_one, open("two.txt") as file_two:
    if OrderedDict(Counter(file_one)) == OrderedDict(Counter(file_two)):
        print("matched")
    else:
        print("not macthed")
```

Comment: Note that this will just tell if both files contain identical lines but not necessarily in identical order.

Comment: @jamesdlin I thought he just wants to compare two files.

Comment: Would you consider one file containing `foo\nbar\n` to be the same as another file containing `bar\nfoo\n`?

Comment: @jamesdlin got it. thanks i updated the answer i hope that will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to read both files using `f.read()` where `f` is the file being opened in read (`'r'`) mode. The `read()` operation returns the string content of the files.

We then compare the read content of the files using `==` to determine if the sequence of strings are identical.

Letting `fileA`, `fileB` be existent filenames, Hence, the minimal file-comparison code should be:

```
  f = open(fileA, 'r')
  contentA = f.read()
  f.close()
  f = open(fileB, 'r')
  contentB = f.read()
  f.close()

  result = "No"
  if contentA == contentB:
    result = "Yes"
```

You should also handle cases where one of the files are not present (the minimal code returns a traceback if any of `fileA, fileB` refers to a nonexistent file.